# Getting String between Div with the help of Class Name

Tags: c#, html, time

HTML is:

```
<div class="topheader-left common-txt" style="color: #ffffff;vertical-align:top;padding-top:3px">
            &nbsp;Sunday,&nbsp; April&nbsp;&nbsp;28,&nbsp;2013&nbsp;|&nbsp;08:07:07 PM
        </div>
```

I need the value of time which is 08:07:07 which i will convert into time.
I am using this code to Get String of Div Area. for getting substring. Why this is not working?

```
HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = default(HtmlElementCollection);
                theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
                foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
                {
                   if (curElement.GetAttribute("class").ToString() == "topheader-left common-txt")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(curElement.GetAttribute("InnerText"));

                    }
                }
```

Comment: I'd expect this to be much easier using a purpose built HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (XPath) or [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) (jQuery selector syntax)

Comment: HTML Agility Pack configured. what will be the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *HTML Agility Pack configured. what will be the code now.*

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var innerText = doc.DocumentNode
                   .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='topheader-left common-txt']")
                   .InnerText;


DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(innerText).Split('|')[1].Trim(), 
                                    "hh:mm:ss tt",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```